# Model variable not showing initial space

Tags: html, angularjs, css

Hi I have a model variable "name", which is binded to a span like

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name">
<span ng-bind="name"></span>
```

What my requirement is that to show up the text that are entered in the input field without eliminating any spaces.

I find a way to achive that by writing a css property

```css
.allow-spaces{
  white-space:pre;
}
```

so now if I enter a value "hello   ooo buddy" it will show up exactly same in the span as well, but it will not show spaces at the begining like "   hello buddy" is shown as "hello buddy". Please suggest me a solution for this.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and rewrite your question based on the standards outlined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngModel` by default trims beginning and trailing white spaces in `input[type=text]`. To disable this behavior write `ng-trim=false` in the `input` element.

[Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D)